# Call Ruby method with parameters separated by space

Tags: ruby, scripting, parameters

Not sure if this is possible but can I call a method from an irb shell with spaces between parameters rather than commas (don't ask) ? Lets say I have a method

```
def start_band(member1, member2, member3, member4)
    #do something
end
```

And then I call it like the following:

```
irb>> start_band "John" "Paul" "George" "Ringo"
```

**EDIT: Would it be possible to detect every keypress instead?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durr! I really approached this the wrong way. I simply needed to run

```
@members = gets
```

to allow the input as required. Thanks for the responses nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that. Not with strings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You could use something like [treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/) to write a really simple DSL, or just play monkey-parsing games, but that won't solve your exact question.

The other obvious answer is this, which also fails:

```
irb>> start_band %W(John Paul George Ringo)
```

Creating an irb-like CLI isn't difficult, and may be adequate, depending on what your actual requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a very easy way to get rid of the commas. You can even get rid of the quotes, too:

```
def start_band(members)
  #members is an array
end

start_band %w(John Paul George Ringo)
```

The limitation is that you can't use spaces inside your strings, and you still need start-end terminations (can use other characters instead of parenthesis though).

Comment: You can use spaces inside the strings, you just have to escape them: `>> %w[foo\ bar] #=> ["foo bar"]`.